# why java connection cannot createstatement() while an executeQuery() is in the middle of processing ?

Tags: java, static, executequery

I have a static java connection to a databases.

**1st Thread**

with my static connection I am creating a statement and call to executeQuery() method. at this point I'm waiting because the query results is very big and I have to wait more than 15 minutes.

**2nd Thread**

with the same static connection I am trying to make a call to createStatement() method. And here the 2nd thread is blocked.

There are many ways to solve this issue, but I don't find anywhere why this aproach should not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Without showing us the code we can't tell. You probably have some static synchronized methods or something like that.

Comment: Looks like you are sharing the connection, so this is bound to happen. You might need a DB pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a common way, the single `Connection` to the database is implemented through `Sockets` mechanism. Better to say, that your single `connection` is some kind of pipe, which is using for concrete query which is executing one per time.

It is hard to imagine such *optimal* and high-perfomance code implementation, where though one socket multiple queries and their results are sent in parallel. Such implementation could cause the confusion with data-packets and at least their lost.

As [karmanaut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2155859/karmanaut) mentioned above in comments, you need to implement DB pool, i.e. pool of connections, which will be used for each statement concurrently.